# User Profile picture doesn't appear

Tags: support, bug, profile-page

My Chem SE account is registered through my Google account. So obviously my Google profile picture was the one set for my Chem SE account as well. Few months earlier I had changed my Google profile picture and the change was in effect on this site as well. Everything was working fine until a few days earlier when my profile picture was replaced by a *cross in the middle of a white background* (indicating invalid I suppose), even when I had not messed with it **at all** (neither here nor in my Google account). I tried to update it several times it shows the change for a few seconds but when I close and reopen this site the *cross* comes up again. I tried clearing cache from my browser thinking that the problem is only with me, but recently I saw another user whose profile picture was the same *cross* as mine. So it might be possible that few more users are facing the same issues. Neither could I find any related information through previous question-answers on this iste.
Though it doesn't hinder my participation here, but its irritating all the same.

So I would be very obliged if someone could explain what could possibly be going wrong, and provide some suggestions so that I can troubleshoot this issue . Any help is very much welcome.

Comment: I can't tell you where things went wrong, the log shows that your avatar is linked to some Google server. On the main site the link works, on meta not so much. Hopefully someone with more insight so to us in. In the meantime I suggest uploading an image to stack exchange itself, this way there won't be nothingness.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン My avatar doesn't appear anywhere on SE, neither the main or meta site. I tried uploading an image of SE itself many a times but all in vain (as mentioned in the question), the image gets shown as uploaded for sometime then when I close and reopen this site, the same *cross* appears again. Or else why would one continue with this *nothingness* :(( I can only use identicons as it appears, but I can wait till this problem gets solved.

Comment: The log of this site shows a link. This one is working on main, but the one on meta is not. The log does not show that you have ever tried to use a different picture than the one from Google. There is nothing else I can report. I don't believe that this issue is very high on the list of the developers. It might be a good idea to contact them via email. (Btw. I see no avatar at all, not a cross of anything. Just a blank space.)

Comment: @Martin-マーチン    https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6KcQ.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZNQ9.png here are the 2 images showing that I tried uploading a new picture altogether on SE main site as avatar. But then reopening the site shows me that blank space again. Yeah you might call it blank space the cross is just at the top corner. Also I already found  2 different users facing the same problem.

Comment: @Pushies and Marva Jami have the same *blank* with a cross in their avatars. I'm hereby attaching a image of the same without their consent, I beg pardon in advance and sincerely hope that they won't have any objections about this, since its being used purposefully. https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYaWV.png

Comment: I can only tell you, what I can see in the log. Please contact support for this issue, they will have more insight into the page and can better investigate the problem.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Thanks for the guidance :) I have reported the issue to support, waiting for a reply...Sorry for wasting your valuable time. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I literally forgot to thank you again for the help. The issue is solved now (its been too late to report though), contacting support very much did it.

Comment: No worries, I saw the image, so I was happy it turned out well.